# Why is my code with chars messing up a counting variable?

Tags: c++, arduino-c++

This is Arduino code, but I have a feeling my error is with C++ in general and not specific to Arduino. I'm new to pointers and strings, so I probably am doing something wrong in that regard.

This is from a much larger program, but I've whittled it down to as little code as I can where I can still reproduce the bug.

It should just iterate through the letters of `text[]` and save each letter into `newText[0][0]`, as well as print `newText[0][0]` and the counter variable `i`.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  const char text[] = "chunk";
  static char newText[][10] = {};

  static unsigned int i=0;
  static int code = 0;     

  if(code == 0){
    
      newText[0][0] = text[i]; //This
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.println(newText[0][0]); //This
      
      i++;
      
      if(i>=strlen(text)){
        code=1;
      }
  }
}
```

But as I have the code, `i` jumps to some number like 104 by the second iteration, when it should be equal to 1. (The exact value varies depending on how exactly the code looks.) If I comment out either of the lines that have the comment `//This`, then the counter works fine. Also, if I switch `Serial.print(i);` and the line before it, then it counts fine.

Comment: You seem to be writing past the end of newText. You've left out its first dimension & are using an empty initializer for it.

Comment: Random connection:  104 is the ASCII code for a lower case `h` (the second character of your string)  Coincidence perhaps.

Comment: @Wyck I think you're right! It was actually 105. But when I change the second letter to something else, it exactly matches the difference in ASCII. If the letter is `m`, the value becomes 110. Good eye.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
static char newText[][10] = {};
```

This creates a zero sized array (to be more precise a matrix of 0 rows and 10 columns). This would be illegal in C++ but gcc has an extension to allow it. Nevertheless even with gcc's extension, it's UB when you access `newText[0][0]` which is outside the size of the array. When you have UB anything can happen, the program can appear to work as you expect, it can print gibberish, it can crash, etc., literally anything.

So you need to declare a size that accommodates all your accesses, e.g.:

```
static char newText[1][10] = {};
```

if you only want 1 row (but in this case you don't need a matrix, a one dimension array would do fine).

---

Tip: use the [String](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) class for strings instead of raw arrays.

Comment: Oh! I should have noticed that. Thank you, it works now. I've been using chars because they seem simpler than String. But I'll look into how String works.